# Find a generator for vectorial subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

S = {$(a, b, c, d) ∈ C^4 : 2ia = b, c + d − ib = 0$} 
$c+d-i(2ia)=0$
$c+d+2a=0$
$c=-d-2a$
$(a,2ia,-2a-d,d)=a(1,2i,-2,0)+d(0,0,-1,1)$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Your title says looking for "a" generator, but you have found *two generators*, namely $(1,2i,-2,0)$ and $(0,0,-1,1)$.

Comment: I don't know if in english it is called generator, i need a set of vectors that generate the space by linear combinations